# Set rules for form validation in two different ways

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter-3

I have all my rules in a file located at `/config/form_validation.php`:

```
$config = array(
    'cadastro_pessoa_fisica' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'imagem',
            'label' => 'IMAGEM',
            'rules' => 'callback__validate_image_file'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'nome_razao_social',
            'label' => 'NOME',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        ...
        ...
```

But I have one rule being set directly in the controller. It is a rule that, when editing the user's information and the e-mail has changed, to apply these rules before proceeding:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $this->input->post('tipo_usuario') === 'F' ? $validator = 'editar_pessoa_fisica' : $validator = 'editar_pessoa_juridica';

    if ($this->input->post('email') !== $this->input->post('novoemail')) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-MAIL', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[usuario.email]');
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run($validator)) {...}
```

The problem is only the e-mail rules show any error. If I leave the name, phone and email fields in blank, the error message is only for the e-mail field. It seems only the validation rules in the controller are seen, when they fail.

**Edit**

This is how the edit form is being populated. When logging in, the user's id is stored in the session, and when accessing the edit view, a query is made to bring the user's information.

```
public function edit_panel()
{
    if ($this->session->has_userdata('email')) {
        $data['id_usuario'] = $this->session->userdata('id_usuario');
        $data['usuario'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get($data['id_usuario']);
        $data['page'] = $this->config->item('admin_template_dir_auto') . $this->redirect_to_user_panel(true);
        $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Cadastre-se ou entre para acessar');
        redirect('/cadastro', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate the form in view when open edit page? Is there `set_value('email')` function?

Comment: The `id` is caught from the session, after logging in. No, the edit forms does not have `set_value`  because it does not print anything. It simply has `$variable->field` within `value` attribute. I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you have two fields for mail? Old mail and new mail? Need to be retyped? Since you have this in your code `$this->input->post('email') !== $this->input->post('novoemail')`.